# if...else within JSP or JSTL

Tags: jsp, if-statement, jstl

I want to output some HTML code based on some condition in a JSP file.

```
if (condition 1) {
    Some HTML code specific for condition 1
}
else if (condition 2) {
    Some HTML code specific for condition 2
}
```

How can I do that? Should I use JSTL?

Comment: Exampledepot has some nice examples. Have a look > http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/if.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use if-else option in JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587397/how-to-use-if-else-option-in-jstl)

Answer (score 607, accepted):

> Should I use JSTL ?

Yes.

You can use `<c:if>` and `<c:choose>` tags to make conditional rendering in jsp using JSTL.

To simulate **if** , you can use:

```xml
<c:if test="condition"></c:if>
```

To simulate **if...else**, you can use:

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.enter=='1'}">
        pizza. 
        <br />
    </c:when>    
    <c:otherwise>
        pizzas. 
        <br />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thx for that...Actually I am more into UI dev...So do not have much knowledge of JSTL..Could you please provide me a similar working example of JSTL..I mean for if..else

Comment: Thx for the example..The condition I have is actually a JS condition..if navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null
So can I write that directly in the if test="condition"..

Comment: well JSTL will execute at server end it will crate HTML out of it and pass it to client

Comment: Ok..that's fine...But for the actual condition i.e.in the test="condition" ...Can I specify any JS condition and if yes, can I write it directly e.g. Can I write <c:when test="navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;">

Comment: can you update your question with the condition you want to test

Answer (score 182):

If you just want to output different text, a more concise example would be

```
${condition ? 'some text when true' : 'some text when false'}
```

It is way shorter than *c:choose*.

Comment: is this javascript or .jsp?

Comment: not working when using a boolean variable as condition any suggest?

Comment: Does this need to be enclosed in a special tag, or just paste this directly into HTML?

Comment: @otherDewi: It's JSTL, which can be used in a JSP file. The conditional or ternary operator exists in many other languages though, including Javascript.

Comment: `$"{condition ? 'what\"s up' : ' \" '}"` you can also do it like this if you need to have a quote in it.

Comment: @bergie3000: **No**, this is not [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). This is [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

Comment: @BalusC Oh you're right. The rest of the statement basically holds up though.

Comment: Take note that a ternary selector on jsp's can't get a ${value} between the 'commas' (with Spring Boot at least)

Answer (score 116):

The construct for this is:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${..}">...</c:when> <!-- if condition -->
   <c:when test="${..}">...</c:when> <!-- else if condition -->
   <c:otherwise>...</c:otherwise>    <!-- else condition -->
</c:choose>
```

If the condition isn't expensive, I sometimes prefer to simply use two distinct `<c:if` tags - it makes it easier to read.

Comment: Can I assume that if first when condition is satisfied, then the second when will not be executed ?

Comment: because you get content assist out-of-the-box, for a start. And because webdevs can use it without learning yet-another-dsl

Comment: @hop no you cannot

Answer (score 13):

In case you want to **compare strings**, write the following JSTL:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${myvar.equals('foo')}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${myvar.equals('bar')}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I think you can only invoke methods (like .equals) on new(ish) containers, like Tomcat 7+.

Answer (score 13):

```
<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>
<c:set var="val" value="5"/>
<c:choose> 
  <c:when test="${val == '5'}">
    Value is 5
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    Value is not 5
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 8):

simple way :

```
<c:if test="${condition}">
    //if
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!condition}">
    //else
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write if-else condition inside `<% %>` in jsp pages and html code outside of `<% %>`

For example:

```
   <%
        String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
        if(username==null)  {
    %>            
        <p> username is null</p> //html code
    <%
        } else {
    %>
        <p> username is not null</p> //html code
    <%
        }
    %>
```

Comment: Tank you! It was solution for my problem, but this syntax is disgusting.... But thank you again!

Comment: please don't do this. Null pointers are undiagnosable when using scriptlets.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>
<c:set var="isiPad" value="value"/>
<c:choose>
   <!-- if condition -->
   <c:when test="${...}">Html Code</c:when> 
   <!-- else condition -->
   <c:otherwise>Html code</c:otherwise>   
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<c:if test="${any_cond}" var="condition">
    //if part
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!condition}">
    //else part
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to compare strings, write the following JSTL :

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${myvar.equals('foo')}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${myvar.equals('bar')}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty userid and userid ne null}">
      <sql:query dataSource="${dbsource}" var="usersql">
                SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE ID = ?;
                <sql:param value="${param.userid}" />
      </sql:query>
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise >
       <sql:query dataSource="${dbsource}" var="usersql">
                 SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE username = ?;
                 <sql:param value="${param.username}" />
       </sql:query>                              
  </c:otherwise>
```

Comment: It may provide the solution but please consider adding some details with code

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:if test="${condition1 && condition2 && condition3}" var="condition">
    //if
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!condition}">
    //else
</c:if>
```

This is an another way to take the if condition in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the following by using JSTL Tag Libe, please follow the following steps:

[Requirement] if a number is a grater than equal 40 and lower than 50 then display "Two digit number starting with 4" otherwise "Other numbers".

[Solutions]

```
1. Please Add the JSTL tag lib on the top of the page.`
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

2. Please Write the following code
`
<c:choose>
       <c:when test="${params.number >=40 && params.number <50}">
              <p> Two digit number starting with 4. </p>
       </c:when>
       <c:otherwise>
              <p> Other numbers. </p>
       </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>`
```