# How to use expression tags in Spring MVC 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3.1. I want to show values from my models in my asp and sometimes I need to use conditional logic. I know about JSTL tags but I'm wondering if there is a better alternative shipped with 3.1?

Currently I show model values in jsp like so: `${model.name}`

But I want to do stuff like: `if name is John then do X or else do Y`

I don't want to have thymleaf dependency.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I might as well note that the whole concept of having logic in the jsp has been shown over and over to bite you eventually. Many have experienced the pain. That being said, it can be used carefully to good effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer:**
Spring does not ship with something that duplicates (or eases) the JSTL tags.

**The long answer:**
I think for JSP Spring expects that JSTL is the way to go for a taglib. Spring does have a taglib, but it is all about filling in forms with your model.

I would strongly discourage using `${model.attribute}` for placing text in a page, especially if the text has come from any form of user input. For security reasons when working with user-entered data you should use `c:out` to ensure the text is properly escaped.

You can do your conditional with `c:if` or `c:choose`.  The accepted answer to [if...else within JSP or JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935892/if-else-within-jsp-or-jstl) may help with that.

Answer (score 0):

With JSP 2.0 Expression Language you may use the "Ternary/Conditional" operator:

E.g.

```
<p>${myobj.test == xy ? 'hello' : 'nohello'}</p>
```