# How to compare 0 and 1 using strut tags

Tags: java, struts

I am getting value 0 and one from database, and i want to compare that value in my jsp page,
I tried below code, but its not comparing correctly.

```
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="%{#groupProfileView.userinfo. profilePrivacy}== 1">
          creator name: ${groupProfileView.userinfo.firstName}
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>anonmous</c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
```

Comment: mixture of OGNL & JSTL - doesn't seem like a good idea

Answer (score 1):

If `profilePrivacy` is a number, try the next:

```
<c:when test="${groupProfileView.userinfo.profilePrivacy == 1}">
```

If `profilePrivacy` is a string, try the next:

```
<c:when test="${groupProfileView.userinfo.profilePrivacy == '1'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
<c:when test='${groupProfileView.userinfo.profilePrivacy eq "1"'>
```

---

**Related**

- [if...else within JSP or JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935892/if-else-within-jsp-or-jstl/5935934#)

Comment: still its not working.  it is always taking otherwise condition.

Comment: i tried like this <c:when test='${groupProfileView.userinfo.profilePrivacy} == "1" '>

Comment: try <c:when test='${groupProfileView.userinfo.profilePrivacy == "1"}  '>

Comment: use <c:out></c:out> and check what the value returning.