# Converting MYSQL Result-set from JSP into Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, jsp

I'm trying to convert a MySQL result-set written in a Java Server Page (.jsp), into a Javascript array that I can graph.

My current MYSQL result-set returns this in the web browser:

I want to return this in Javascript. It must be in this format so I can graph it with d3 or Highcharts :

```
       var ValueArray = [ {x:0, y:110}, {x:15, y:113}, {x:30, y:90} ]
```

After my MYSQL query is run, I create a table using the following java server tags...

```
<script>
var ValueArray=  [
 <c:forEach var="row" items="${meanvalue.rowsByIndex}">
         <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">, 
                     {<c:out value= "${column}"/>}
 </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>
 ]
</script>
```

This is the corresponding HTML code that is generated and is the current output of my MYSQL query:

```
<table border="1" id = "meanvalue">
<!-- column headers -->
<tr>

    <th>timestamp</th>

    <th>Value</th>
```

```
<tr>

  <td>  0</td>  

  <td>  110</td>  

</tr>

<tr>

  <td>  15 </td>  

  <td>  113</td>  

</tr>

<tr>

  <td>  30</td>  

  <td>  90</td>  

</tr>
```

I've searched around stackoverflow and have found similar questions, but none of them have the formatting constraint that I'm looking for; converting a raw number array into a .js array with the format

```
  var Array = [{x: val1, y: val2}, {x: val3, y: val4} ]
```

Comment: From your current attempts what are you getting as output? It also looks like you're missing a comma after your `c:out` section.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.   Currently my results are of the form [ {0},{10}, {15},{113},{30},{90}] so not exactly what I want...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to edit your foreach statements. Something like the following

```
 <c:forEach var="row" items="${meanvalue.rowsByIndex}">
         { // <-- begin the object
         <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}" varStatus="status">, 
                 ${status.index} : <c:out value= "${column}"/>
         </c:forEach>
         } // <-- end the object
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  This then appends "0:" and "1:" in front of the variables I want . Is there a way to convert the 0 and 1 to "X" and "Y"?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5935934/577264 I believe that answer will show you how to do `if` and JSP's `choose` statements (choose will simulate `if/else` statements).