# How to create dynamic select options

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Hi this drop down menu

```
<td class="selectBox"><select name="questionType" id="questionType" disabled=""><option value="">--Select--</option><option value="1"id="1">text</option><option value="2"id="2">rating</option><option value="3"id="3">boolean</option><option value="4"id="4">option</option></select></td>
```

and its created dynamically using jstl

```
'<td class="selectBox"><select name="questionType" id="questionType" disabled=""><option value="">--Select--</option><c:forEach items="${questionTypes}" var="questionType"><option value="${questionType.id}"id="${questionType.id}">${questionType.name }</option></c:forEach></select></td>';
```

Now I want to give a class "show-checkboxes" to one of the drop down whose value is option
`<option value="4"id="4" class="show-checkboxes">option</option>`

so I did this jstl

```
'<td class="selectBox"><select name="questionType" id="questionType" disabled=""><option value="">--Select--</option><c:forEach items="${questionTypes}" var="questionType"><c:choose><c:when tes="${questionType.name.equals("option")}"><option class ="show-checkboxes" value="${questionType.id}"id="${questionType.id}">${questionType.name }</option></c:when><c:otherwise><option  value="${questionType.id}"id="${questionType.id}">${questionType.name }</option></c:otherwise></c:choose></c:forEach></select></td>';
```

but its not working

Can any body please tell me the error?

Comment: "*but its not working*" is never good explanation of problem. Be more specific and add informations about what you are getting instead of desired result.

Comment: @Pshemo I am getting errors

Comment: Can we know what kind of errors? Is that not secret?

Comment: @Pshemo no its not scret.But its so long so did not post here you can check http://pastie.org/9198917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<c:when tes="${questionType.name.equals("option")}">
```

with

```
<c:when test="${questionType.name eq \"option\"}">
```

OR

```
<c:when test="${questionType.name eq 'option'}">
```

You are using double quotes inside double quotes that is causing the issue.

Find a sample code here [JSTL Core c:when Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm)

Comment: what is test here?can we write with out using test word?

Comment: I was following this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935892/if-else-within-jsp-or-jstl so put test in my code.

Comment: @rocking this answer and links it provide may help you

Comment: @Braj +1 and i go the 2nd suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In tag

```
<c:when tes="${questionType.name.equals("option")}">
```

the word test is missing last letter. It might be cause of strange behaviour.

Comment: I have removed the word test also but again the same error

Comment: You shouldn't remove it, you should add last letter 't' to the word tes.

Comment: @xwid using double quotes inside double quotes that is causing the issue.