# Using if in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I am trying to use an if condition to display an item or not in one of my JSP files.

I currently have

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(${model.listOfListProducts}) gt 0}">
<p> we got in </p>
</c:if>
```

I am trying to see if the length of one of my Lists< List<>> in my model object is essentially greater than 0 (not null)

But this does not display the paragraph that I have placed inside. Is my test statement syntactically wrong?

Comment: What is `model.listOfListProducts`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it is a List<List<String>> object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `$` from nested expression

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(model.listOfListProducts) gt 0}">
  <p> we got in </p>
</c:if>
```

---

**See Also**

- [if...else within JSP or JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935892/if-else-within-jsp-or-jstl/5935934#5935934)