# How to compare the value in second jsp with another value that is passed from first jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am using this html tag in my jsp page . As you see , I want to send sec_id to wall.jsp . 
but I dont know how exactly can I compare this sec_id with another id that available in 
wall.jsp in if statement.

```
<a href= wall.jsp?sec=<%= res.getInt("sec_id")%> >
```

Comment: how these two jsp files communicate? How first jsp talks with second jsp?

Comment: excuse me there is a mistake in my post. I edit it now.

Comment: so the problem is with sending id or comparing the id?

Comment: no , I dont know how can i compare with other number that is available in wall.jsp

Comment: have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:set value="XYZ" var="anotherId"></c:set>

<c:if test="${param.sec.equals(anotherId)}">
     Matched
</c:if>
```

Here `param.sec` is used to access the value of `sec` from request parameter.

---

You can use `<c:choose>` as well that behave just like a Java Switch statement.

[Find more examples...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935892/if-else-within-jsp-or-jstl)

Comment: actually I don't test it yet but I realize completely what this code do. i sure test it ;) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can even send the data setting it in session

```
session.setAttribute("sec_id", res.getInt("sec_id"));
```

In `wall.jsp` retrieve it from session

```
int sec_id= session.getAttribute("sec_id");
```

then compare the two id's like

```
if(wallJspId==sec_id){
//do something;
}
else{
//do something;
}
```

Comment: so , should i revert this link to a servlet page then forward to  wall.jsp??

Comment: no you can use JSTL as above example said or simple scriptlet(not recommended though)