# JSP dynamic content from query string

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to create a dynamic web page showing different messages according to query string parameter, such as

http://localhost:8080/example?param=10

In my jsp page, to get the parameter i use

```
<%= request.getParameter("param") %>
```

and that correctly evaluates to the correct value. Then i try to combine this with some **IFs** clauses to switch to different content:

```
<% if (request.getParameter("param") == "10") { %>
<!-- show something -->
<%
}
%>
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

If i try

```
<%= if (request.getParameter("param") == "10") { %>
<!-- show something -->
<%
}
%>
```

i get an internal server error.

Which is the correct approach to show dynamic content evaluating the query string parameter?

Thanks

Comment: try like -> `if(request.getParameter("param").equals("10")) { 
<!-- show something --> }`

Comment: sorry i noticed i typed wrong, i edited the question

Comment: so what didn't work? did you try above suggested code ?

Comment: yes, but it didn't work

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935892/if-else-within-jsp-or-jstl) post .

Comment: I tried, but all condition are evaluated as true, so i get every possible outcome of the if-else.
The code is  `<c:if test="<%= request.getParameter('param')%> == '10'"> TEST </c:if>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using JSTL libraries.

First download *jstl-api.jar* and *jstl-impl.jar* and copy them in tomcat's **WEB-INF/lib** directory of your webapp.

Restart tomcat and in your .jsp page add

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

at the beginning of the file

Now declare a new variable with

```
<c:set var="param" value='<%= request.getParameter("param") %>' />
```

Finally, use directives to change the visualization of content based on *param* value

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param == '10'}"> <!-- content --> </c:when>
    <c:when test="${param == '20' || param == '30'}"> <!-- content --> </c:when>
</c:choose>
```