# Equivalent of "if elseif elseif" in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

What is the equivalant of `if()else if()else if()` in JSTL I tried using

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when></c:when>
  <c:when></c:when><c:otherwise> 
  <c:when></c:when>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

but it was giving error.

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587397/how-to-use-if-else-option-in-jstl i think it answers your question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because your mixed up your tags.  It should be:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="..."> ... </c:when>
  <c:when test="..."> ... </c:when>
  <c:otherwise> ... </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```