# How to checked radio button when value retrieve from database in jsp using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

i want to retrieve radio button value in checked radio button in jsp page

```
<% String gen=rs.getString("gender");session.setAttribute("gender",  gen); %>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male"  value="male" />male
     <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female"    value="female" />Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other"   value="other" />
```

Comment: are you using jstl & el?

Comment: yes, but it is possible with javascript than it is better

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`el`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to add `checked` attribute on condition

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" ${gen eq "male"?'checked="checked"':''}/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" ${gen eq "female"?'checked="checked"':''}/>Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other" ${gen eq "other"?'checked="checked"':''}/>
```

Comment: can you explain it?

Comment: Simply `el` provide you with a ternary operator similar to the one that you have in `Java`, I am just using it here to check if `gen` value is equal `eq` to "male", "female" or "other". If true, then I apply the `checked` attribute. If false I apply nothing as `' '`

Comment: Check the [`el`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) tag wiki and this example [here](http://javabeat.net/ternary-operator-in-jsp-2-0-expression-languageel/) for more

Comment: @muneeb,  if it answers your question, kindly mark it as accepted as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each option if this option's value is equal to the gender. If so add checked="checked"

ex:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male"  value="male" <% Response.Write( (gen == "male") ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ) %> />male
```

or you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008011/if-then-else-inside-a-jsp-expression)