# Error using <c:choose> in table with jsp

Tags: jsp, if-statement, html-table

I'm developing web app using jsp.

What I want to do is, if a variable is not null, I'll display it, but if null, I'll display `-` character in table row.

This my code so far, I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587397/how-to-use-if-else-option-in-jstl)

```
<table id="hor-minimalist-a" summary="Employee Pay Sheet">
    <caption>Riwayat Status</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
             <th scope="col">Status</th>
             <th scope="col">Tanggal</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>  
             <td>Tanggal DP</td>
             <c:choose>
               <c:when test="${Transaction.tglDP}">
                <td>${Transaction.tglDP}</td>
               </c:when>
               <c:otherwise}>
                <td>-</td>
               </c:otherwise>
             </c:choose>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But when I run the website, when that variable is not null, it displaying the value and character - too.

What am I missing here?

Edit : for information, Transaction.tglDP type is java.util.Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use not empty for null check, also you dont have to do multiple when if you want if else block just use otherwise

```
<c:choose>
      <c:when test="${not empty  Transaction.tglDP}">
            <td>${Transaction.tglDP}</td>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
            <td>-</td>
      </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: i've tried your suggestion, but the displaying result is still the same, it's like two <td> is displayed whether it's null or not.

Comment: please post more code of yours either when or otherwise will get executed, both is not a possibility

Comment: my code is just like yours, what should i post? i'm sorry i don't understand your comment...

Comment: Only one option will be executed out of c:when or c:otherwise both cannot be executed, so if you have more code in your jsp page, please post that

Comment: @bangandi: your code is not the same as mprabhat's code. Th syntax is `<c:when test="${...}">`, and not `<c:when ${...}>`.

Comment: @JBNizet i'm sorry, i forget to copy all of my updated code from netbeans. I was just adding addition code. Now it's all updated. The result is still the same

Comment: You still have an additional curly bracket in c:otherwise. I'm surprised this even compiles. Look at the generated HTML code (using View page source in your browser). I suspect the JSTL core tag library isn't even declared in the JSP, and that you'll find <c:when> in the generated HTML because the tags are not interpreted as JSP tags by the container.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i know what's wrong with my code. Because I'm new in jsp and the link from my question above didn't mention about using jstl library, i thought it was enough to just code like that. My own mistake.
I didn't include the jstl.1.2.jar in my lib and forget to place this line :

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

And also view answer from @mprabhat .
Thanks for everyone :)