# How to Use If.....Else Using the JSTl tags in the JSP page

Tags: jsp, jstl

Iam getting the status message from the action class.Based on the status message iam displaying the two different images.

If the Status message is "Acces denied" then it show one image in the JSP page.
Else we want to show an different Image.

Comment: I searched lot all are having the code only for the "IF" statement, there is no code for the Else statement.

Comment: refer this [link](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_using_jstl.htm)

Comment: See This - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587397/how-to-use-if-else-option-in-jstl?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

The JSTL, surprisingly, [is documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html), and has an [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakl). Google is your best friend.

You're looking for c:choose, c:when and c:otherwise:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${status.message == 'Access Denied'}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 5):

there is no conditions like if else in jstl instead of that jstl provides following

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${condition1}">
    ...
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${condition2}">
    ...
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    ...
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

for more details refer this [link](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_using_jstl.htm)

Answer (score 0):

JSTL comes with `<c:choose>`, `<c:when>` and `<c:otherwise>` tags to implement `if-then-else` type logic within JSPs. Check out [JSTL Core Choose Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm) for a basic example.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${a boolean expr}">
      <!-- // do something -->
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${another boolean expr}">
      <!-- // do something else -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <!-- // do this when nothing else is true -->
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```