# edit and delete links in table based on if statement

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, jscript

I have the following code, it displays existing sets of cards for a table top game and allows you to edit or delete them. I would like to only allow edit and delete on sets with a weight greater than 100 and display "adminonly" for those that are locked (weight less than 100). is there a simple way to do this, I can provide the full page code if necessary

```
    <h2>Existing card sets</h2>
<table style="1px solid black">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%
      for (PyxCardSet cardSet : cardSets) {
    %>
      <tr>
        <td><%=cardSet.getName()%></td>
        <td><a href="?delete=<%=cardSet.getId()%>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="?edit=<%=cardSet.getId()%>">Edit</a></td>
        <td><%=cardSet.getWeight()%></td>
        <td><%=cardSet.isActive()%></td>
      </tr>
    <%
      }
    %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you not just make links conditional on the weight?  Like, if the weight is too low don't create the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simple inject the `if statement inside the loop` and it will do what you are looking for

```
<tbody>
    <%
      for (PyxCardSet cardSet : cardSets) {
    %>
      <tr>
        <td><%=cardSet.getName()%></td>
        <% if(cardSet.getWeight()>100) { %>
        <td><a href="?delete=<%=cardSet.getId()%>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="?edit=<%=cardSet.getId()%>">Edit</a></td>
        <% } else { %>
         <td>for admin only</td>
        <td>for admin only </td>
        <% } %>
        <td><a href="?edit=<%=cardSet.getId()%>">Edit</a></td>
        <td><%=cardSet.getWeight()%></td>
        <td><%=cardSet.isActive()%></td>
      </tr>
    <%
      }
    %>
  </tbody>
```

i suggest you to use the JSTL expression language , it's not favorable to have JAVA code inside your JSP . see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587397/how-to-use-if-else-option-in-jstl) it may be helpful

Comment: tried the above but it seems to have an issue with the statement

Comment: @SJWilliams sorry i forgot an open `{` now it should work

Comment: For some reason if is still barking about it Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete IfStatement

Comment: @SJWilliams it doesn't show the edit in your hosted version !! it says that you did not edit it

Comment: not sure what you mean, I have the code edited to what you posted but it is giving the syntax error I listed above "Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete IfStatement"

Comment: but, it's not updated in the server !! try it locally

Comment: FIXED IT! Thanks PacMan