# How to access property of display:column and use IF/WHEN conditions properly

Tags: jsp, jstl, displaytag

I have this code:

```
<display:column sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"
         titleKey="form.procedure" property="procedure.procedureName" >
          <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${procedure.procedureName == 'Injection'}">
                        You are using Injection.
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                          <c:out value="${procedure.procedureName}"/>
                        <c:set target="Procedure" property="procedure.proProcedureName" value="${procedure.proProcedureName}" >

                    </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>                
    </display:column>
```

however I get errors. 
Can someone help me write this properly:
Pseudo code is
"When the procedureName is not equal to "Injection" display that procedureName instead."
I don't know if Im even writing my IF/WHEN conditions properly.

BTW I have a POJO class named "Procedure.java" if that's not obvious.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587397/how-to-use-if-else-option-in-jstl ? 
See the comment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263017/3331412

Comment: @comdotlinux it's not the IF/WHEN problem only, it's HOW TO DISPLAY THE POJO PROPERTY as well.

Comment: Arent you missing the opening angle bracket for c:out?
    c:out value="${procedure.procedureName}"/>

Comment: @comdotlinux sorry typo